# How do I set up auto-login on debian (lenny)?

Tags: linux, debian

I'm trying to set-up a barebones installation of lenny that boots straight into a saved xfce session, with no login prompt. Also I'd rater not install gdm (which pulls in a bunch of dependecies) or xdm.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [these](https://web.archive.org/web/20160117095559/http://www.debianadmin.com/how-to-auto-login-and-startx-without-a-display-manager-in-debian.html) instructions on debianadmin.com with two methods for doing this.

OR

If you are using kdm then I believe you should be able to setup automatic login in the KDE control center.

Comment: Nope, not running kde or any fancy GUI stuff. I'd like a mostly command-line system, whit the bare minimum to run a custom GUI program.

Comment: try the link. it might be work for u

Comment: Yep, the link above set me on the right track. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In KDE under Debian 8 jessie it is settable by going to: system settings-> login screen -> convenience -> enable auto-login -> applying by entering your password. Reboot after that.